# CANNOT RENDER A PDF FILE,OBTAINING TEXT FILE INSTEAD OF A PDF

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3.X , using the PLUGIN CAKEPDF

I tried with wkhtmltopdf and dompdf and with both of them I couldn't download a valid PDF file, it downloads a plain text file.

My **bootstrap.php**:

```
Plugin::load('CakePdf', array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true));
my routes.php: .......

Router::scope('/users/view', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions('pdf');
    $routes->connect('/view/*', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view']);
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
......
```

Everything is OK, but when I navigate in my browser to this:

```
/cakephp/users/view/5.pdf
```

I don't get a proper PDF file, instead of that I download a text file like this:
  *(the view ctp seems to work)*

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>    <title>
        Users\pdf    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/fct/css/style.css"/></head>
<body>
<h2>Informe PDF</h2>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="users view">
<h2>User</h2>
    <dl>
        <dt>Id</dt>
        <dd>
            2            &nbsp;
        </dd>

        <dt>Username</dt>
        <dd>
            tutor666            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt>Created</dt>
        <dd>
            8/5/16, 7:34 PM            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt>Modified</dt>
        <dd>
            8/5/16, 7:34 PM            &nbsp;
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So maybe my **router.php** is wrong?...

```
Router::scope('/users/view', function ($routes) { $routes->extensions('pdf'); $routes->connect('/view/*', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view']); $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
```

reviewing the cakepdf docs it seems *"/cakephp/users/view/5.pdf"* is the right way....but it stills download a text file instead of a PDF file. feel Desperate!

The file should be 'User_15.pdf' but is '15.pdf, so maybe this code is not working:

```
UsersController:View(): $this->viewBuilder()->options([ 'pdfConfig' => [ 'orientation' => 'portrait', 'filename' => 'User_' . $id . '.pdf' ] ]);
```

I look at the debug history and says "GET 200 application/pdf " 
 but as you can see above I download a Text/Text header.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I implement CakePdf. I use DomPdf as it can be installed via composer.

Step 1. Install cakepdf plugin

```
composer require friendsofcake/cakepdf
```

Step 2. Install the DomPdf Engind

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf
```

Step 3. Make sure you have RequestHandler Component loaded in you AppController.php ([rootdir]/src/AppController.php)

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}
```

Step 4. Enable the CakePdf plugin in bootstrap.php

```
Plugin::load('CakePdf', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

Step 5. Setup the appropriate routes in routes.php

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['pdf']);
    /** Other route setup **/
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

Step 6. Create a pdf folder under your Templates/Layouts folder and create a pdf.ctp file to contain the following

```
<?= $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

The above acts as a blank layout for your pdf. You can use whatever markup is appropriate for your case

Step 7. In the Template folder you want to generate pdfs for in your cases users (I'm assuming [rootdir]/Templates/Users/), create a pdf folder and then create a view file in the pdf folder (i.e [rootdir]/Templates/Users/pdf/view.ctp). This will contain the markup for the view.
For this example use

```
<?= $show;?>
```

Step 8. Now in your controller function (assuming view also). it should contain the following

```
public function view () {
    /** I'm only displaying "text" on my pdf file **/
    $show = "text";

    $this->viewBuilder()->options([
        'pdfConfig' => [
            'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
            'orientation' => 'portrait',
            'filename' => 'Pdf view'
            /** Other config options can go here**/
        ]
    ]);

    $this->set(compact('show'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['show']);
}
```

Step 9. Point your browser to [webpath]/users/view.pdf and you should have  a pdf file showing "text"

You can adapt it to your needs

Cheers.